# Does Angular/Ionic run in the car systems from Google/Apple?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, android-auto, carplay

We want to build an app that also supports Android Auto and Apple Carplay.
We are using Angular/Ionic but I cannot find out if it runs in the car systems.

Does anyone have experience or an answer with this?

Comment: as nobody answered... I guess you moved forward anyway. Were you able to make the app in Ionic and run in Android Auto? Thanks!

Comment: @fernaramburu after further research I came to the conclusion that this is for now not possible with Angular/Ionic. Also Carplay has very limited restrictions about which apps may run on it. We decided to skip this requirement for now. I think the Car-system-world is to young and it might change in the future.